# QCC r package chart format

Tags: r, statistics, qcc

I was wondering if there is a way to format the chart I have. I would like to make the CL, UCL, LCL, all dashed and red if possible. And I would also like to add titles on the axes along with a title on the graph. Lastly is there a way to remove the word "Group" that is between the x values on the chart. And if possible to remove the all the numerical information on the bottom of the graph where the "Number of groups", all the way to "Number violating Limits".

Here is the image of the chart.

[image]

Here is the code I have

```
> dfdata3 <- subset(dfdata2, Result.Display.Name == "Acidic", select = c(Batch.Name, Result.Display.Name, Raw.Number))

> dput(dfdata3)

> dfdata3 <- structurestructure(list(Batch.Name = c(709193, 727237, 735888, 739385, 
744463, 754696, 758427, 764049, 767737, 773521, 775288, 779685, 
783587, 789615, 793264, 793267, 799742, 805242, 806944, 817990, 
834100, 839833, 840997, 844117, 899453, 901736, 902704, 909566, 
932314, 938959, 943670, 949107, 949108, 958033, 960403, 965089, 
965094, 969527, 974089, 975530, 985677, 993664, 995169, 999804, 
999806, 1014045, 1016961, 1022456, 1031359, 1031360, 1031363, 
1044422, 1044423, 1056867, 1061492), Result.Display.Name = c("Acidic", 
"Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", 
"Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", 
"Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", 
"Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", 
"Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", 
"Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", 
"Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", 
"Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic"), Raw.Number = c(0.8663, 
1.1192, 0.9437, 0.7085, 0.7795, 0.6441, 1.1545, 0.6833, 0.6501, 
0.6356, 0.76, 0.9555, 1.1653, 0.8426, 0.6744, 0.7051, 0.68, 0.7491, 
0.5169, 0.6475, 0.558, 0.5824, 0.7212, 0.7082, 1.096, 0.8891, 
1.1216, 0.7707, 0.7974, 0.6866, 1.7159, 0.9256, 0.7399, 0.637, 
0.7955, 0.8347, 0.5414, 0.491, 0.6045, 0.6234, 0.6149, 0.6937, 
0.8356, 0.5532, 0.6118, 0.5189, 0.4556, 0.5575, 0.7982, 0.8283, 
1.463, 0.6836, 0.5276, 0.6439, 0.6471)), row.names = c(10L, 67L, 
124L, 181L, 238L, 295L, 352L, 409L, 466L, 520L, 577L, 634L, 691L, 
748L, 805L, 862L, 919L, 976L, 1033L, 1090L, 1147L, 1204L, 1261L, 
1318L, 1375L, 1432L, 1489L, 1546L, 1603L, 1660L, 1717L, 1774L, 
1831L, 1888L, 1945L, 2002L, 2059L, 2116L, 2173L, 2230L, 2287L, 
2344L, 2401L, 2458L, 2515L, 2572L, 2629L, 2686L, 2743L, 2800L, 
2857L, 2914L, 2971L, 3028L, 3114L), class = "data.frame")

> attach(dfdata3)

> dfdata3_grp <- qcc.groups(Raw.Number, Batch.Name)

> qcc(dfdata3_grp, type = "xbar.one")

> DataMat <- matrix(dfdata3$Raw.Number, ncol = 1)

> dimnames(DataMat) <- list(dfdata3$Batch.Name, "value")

> qcc(DataMat, type = "xbar.one", axes.las = 2)
```

Comment: I realize this post is several months old. Did you ever figure this out? I've had some success doing what you mentioned you were trying to do.